# How to send an intent from an app to open a file with text editor app?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a base app, and would like to open a specific text file with a text editor app called QuickEdit.

I'm able to successfully do it with activitymanager like this:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -n com.rhmsoft.edit.pro/com.rhmsoft.edit.activity.MainActivity -d file:///storage/emulated/0/file.txt
```

That gives me the exact result I'm looking for: the file is opened and ready for editing in the QuickEdit app.

I've tried to replicate the successful am command as an intent in my base app. It opens the QuickEdit app, but it does not open the specific app I'm aiming for.

```
Intent intent = new Intent ();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setComponent(new ("com.rhmsoft.edit.pro","com.rhmsoft.edit.activity.MainActivity"));
Uri uri = Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/file.txt");
intent.setData(uri);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(intent);
```

I've tried many many things in thh manifest, is there any suggestions on the manifest and/or current java code?

Comment: You do not have the same `Uri`, and the one that you are parsing is not a valid `Uri`. Also, you can remove `addFlags()`, since your code has no rights to the file in question.

Comment: If I put the "file://" header, the app doesn't open altogether, as opposed to at least opening without the target file

Comment: Then look at Logcat and see what errors the other app is reporting. It may not have rights to work with that file either.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Uri.parse().

Use FileProvider to get an uri for your file.

And keep the flag.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. Why does Uri.parse() work for opening a directory with my file manager app, but not a file with my text editor app?